# After a factory reset the restore of SMS, call-history etc. fails

Tags: backup, factory-reset

I turned on "backup to google drive" using an account on a "legacy free edition of Google Apps" domain and then factory reset my Pixel 3. When I worked through the re-configuration, at the very end, the restore failed with a message saying "`Couldn't finish restoring the backup`". Several attempts at re-running this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

My working theory is that the failure is due to the default installed version of the apps in question, after a factory reset, being older than the version that created the backup before the factory reset. What is needed is to defer the restore-from-backup (which seems to be impossible to directly trigger once the initial setup is "done") until after they are all updated.

What ended up working was to do the following:

- During the initial setup bypass adding an account at all and defer as much setup as possible (remind me later, skip, etc.). As soon as possible, get a home screen. (I just left the setup screens idle in the background.)
- Once at a basic home screen,use the app update screen and prompt an immediate update of ***everything***,
- Wait for those updates to completely finish.
- Then, add the primary account.
- Finally, resumed the setup, hope and pray that that it will now attempt the restore from backup using the newly added account.

I'm likely missing a number of details so you may have to try this several times to figure out exactly what things take.

Another thing I did, which might have an effect, was to restore only the thing I actually needed, ... but my gut says that wasn't the big difference that made it work.

Comment: Your approach sounded promising, but unfortunately did not have any positive effect for me. There was also (in Android 13, so probably a few versions later than what you used) not much to update, while the rest required a login to the Google Account, which then of course kicks off the remaining flow we're trying to delay. So I updated those ~5 system apps, even rebooted once, then started the actual restore process, but it would still fail with the generic message.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears to be caused by Google Workspace domains which have policies set which require connected devices to have passwords/PINs/patterns. Which is the default for Workspace domains. But during initial setup on many phones, this happens before one has the chance to *set* a password/pin/pattern/whatever.

The method above presumably works because you have set up a PIN before trying to conenct a Google account - and it's probably the best way to do it.

An alternative solution, which I just followed successfully, is to turn off this requirement for the domain using the instructions at https://support.google.com/a/answer/6328679. This does, of course, require you to have permission to adjust admin settings for the Google domain.